# Converting char to ASCII symbol

Tags: c#

So I want to make "hello world!" in a creative way and I came up with and idea to use ASCII but I don't realy now how to convert from char to ASCII symbol (neither from string). Here is my code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> imie = new List<string>();

    greet();
}
public static string greet()
{
    string s = "";
    string nums = "104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33";
    char[] numbers = nums.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char l in numbers)
    {
        s += Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] {l});
    }

    return s;
}
```

Also in line "s += Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] {l});" I am getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: I don't think the `ToCharArray()` method does what you think it does. For example, the resulting `numbers` array will have 45 elements, not 12. And when you do that, each `l` in the loop will have values like `1`, `0`, `5`, `<space>`, `1`, not `104`, `101`, etc

Comment: I assume you should split on space, then convert each part (1st one is 104) to int, then cast to char

Comment: *I am getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'byte'* - it's true. There are 65536 chars, but only 256 bytes, hence why you have to be explicit about your desire to convert a char to a byte; saying `new byte[] { (byte)l }` is you telling C# "I know that this might cause information loss, and I want `l` converted to a byte anyway"

Comment: but why? a C# char is utf16 and utf16 is basically a superset of 7bit ASCII. Where the first 128 symbols of utf16 are 1:1 the ASCII symbols...

Comment: Tip: find out the Length of your 'numbers'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
   public static string greet() {
        string s = "";
        string nums = "104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33";
        var numbers = nums.Split(" ");
        foreach (var nstr in numbers) {
            int k = Int32.Parse(nstr);
            s += Convert.ToChar(k);

        }

        return s;
    }
```

or better (appending to a string is very ineffiecint)

```
  public static string greet() {
        StringBuilder s = "";
        string nums = "104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33";
        var numbers = nums.Split(" ");
        foreach (var nstr in numbers) {
            int k = Int32.Parse(nstr);
            s.Append(Convert.ToChar(k));

        }

        return s.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if posting code without explanation can be considered helpful.

Comment: At least pm100 shows how *not to* construct strings inside loop. I don't think adding explanations would be nice as it would mean telling OP they code is ... not a canonical way of building string.

Answer (score 1):

Quite creative, but it seems that the level of creativity does not match the level of your C# knowledge yet... There are many misunderstandings, which makes answering this question a bit hard.

Let's start in the `Main()` method:

1. you don't use the variable

   ```
   List<string> imie = new List<string>();
   ```

   but actually, that type of list would be useful in a different place of the program. For the moment, let's put this line of code inside the `greet()` method instead.
2. you call `greet()` which returns a string, but you never use the return value. Let's surround this by a print statement:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(greet());
   ```

The Main() method now looks like

```cs
public static void Main()
{   
    Console.WriteLine(greet());
}
```

Let's go on with the `greet()` method.

3. the variable `s`  is not very descriptive. Let's rename it to `helloworld`, so you have a better idea of what it's being used for.
4. Instead of using a single string, let's take the idea of having a list of strings instead.

```cs
List<string> numbers = new List<string>{"104", "101", "108", "108", "111", "32", "119", "111", "114", "108", "100", "33"};
```

5. We can now get rid of `nums` and the old `numbers` variables. We don't need those.
6. The `for` loop gives you a `string` instead of single characters (which would have been individual digits of the numbers actually). Let's also change the variable name.

```cs
foreach (string number in numbers)
```

It's good practice to have singular and plural in for loops.

7. For the string concatenation, let's use `int.Parse()` instead of further messing with individual digits of a character. In order for the number to become a character, we need to cast it to a `char`

```cs
helloworld += (char) int.Parse(number);
```

The method:

```cs
public static string greet()
{
    List<string> numbers = new List<string>{"104", "101", "108", "108", "111", "32", "119", "111", "114", "108", "100", "33"};  
    string helloworld = "";
    foreach (string number in numbers)
    {
        helloworld += (char) int.Parse(number);
    }
    return helloworld;
}
```

Comment: This list called "imie" I forgot it was even there I was testing smt and forgot to delete this and later i added console line to see the actual result

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string greet()
{
    string nums = "104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33";
    var bytes = nums.Split().Select(n => byte.Parse(n)).ToArray();
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes);
}
```

Comment: You probably should add paragraph about doing something with result of the function... as OP did not show that their know how to use methods that return value and likely expected `void` with `Console.WriteLine` inside `Greet` method (why would you suggest lowercase for `greet` ?)